# How to set the default time zone for Joda's DateTime.parse()

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to use Joda Time to parse times that have no explicit time zone with a particular default zone (UTC for example), but use the explicit zone if present.  For example:

```
parse("2014-02-11T12:00:00")       // Should be UTC
parse("2014-02-11T12:00:00+02:00") // Should be +2 hours
```

Everything I've tried has some problem:

```
DateTime.parse("2014-02-11T12:00:00") // Gives the server time zone, -5 hours

ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()
        .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
        .parseDateTime("2014-02-11T12:00:00+02:00"); // Gives UTC
```

Basically I want the behaviour of `withZone()` and `withOffsetParsed()` at the same time, but they override each other.

I don't want to change the default time zone of the whole JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the answer while I was typing the question.  Since a quick Google didn't find the answer, I figured I'd post it.  The solution is:

```
ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()
        .withChronology(ISOChronology.getInstance(timeZone))
        .withOffsetParsed()
        .parseDateTime(...);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Looks like you inlined the standard `DateTime.parse()` method, and inserted that extra `withChronology()` call.